# Selenium,FireFox, Куки

Tags: python

Hачал осваивать модуль `Selenium`, скачал модуль, драйвера, браузер Firefox.
В самом браузере я уже заранее авторизировался на специальном сайте, но при открытие этого сайта через Selenium, браузер показывает, что я на этом сайте не авторизирован. Скорее всего при открытие сайта, скрипт не использует cookie браузера. 
Как сделать так, что бы он их использовал?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

geckodriver_path = 'G:\WORK\Python\ВК\SampStoreBot\geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path =geckodriver_path)
driver.get("https://samp-store.ru/")
input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй библиотеку requests для передачи куков. Вот [документация](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#cookies)